# Как выбрать из бд в массив, а потом снова выбрать из бд все строки с данными из этого массива?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть таблица *whois* со столбцами *who1*, *who2*, *status*. Нужно выбрать из этой таблицы все строки, где или *who1* или *who2* равен, например, "*glados*" и поместить данные выбранных строк в массив. После нужно из таблицы *whereis* выбрать все строки по массиву, в которых *author* равно всем выбранным сначала *who1* или *who2*, но не равно "*glados*".

Я не могу придумать, как это реализовать. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Заранее спасибо.

**Обновление**

Например, в первой таблице есть who1=glados, who2=moomoo, ststus=2 и прочие строки с разными данными. Нужно выбрать из этой таблицы who1 и who2 из строк, где status=2 и who1 или who2 = glados.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что должно извлекаться из первой таблицы.
Можно пример данных?

Comment: @ReaGedCorp, Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вложеным запросом, если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
SELECT `wh`.* FROM `whereis` as wh WHERE `wh`.`author` IN (SELECT `w`.`id` WHERE `whois` as `w` WHERE (`w`.`who1`='glados' OR `w`.`who2`='glados') AND `w`.`status`='2')
```

Comment:   > в которых author равно всем выбранным сначала who1 или who2, но не равно "glados".

@AlhambR, вы последнюю часть условия забыли.